# Do something according to some schedule in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, apache, mono

I need to do some job for example every Monday and Sunday at 7 o'clock. I've written web service, that can do this job, but I don't know how to execute this web service at required time. Could anybody help me?

P.S. I use Mono and mod_mono on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows, you would normally create a console based application to call the web service and it would be added to the Task Scheduler.

For Mac OS X, you could try doing something similar and using cron. Check out [this post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714).

Comment: The same way you call the web service in Windows.  Consume it, and invoke the web methods.  Add a web reference to the console app, specifying the Url of the service.  A proxy wrapper will be created. (Assuming you're using web services not WCF).

Comment: @ create a c# application and add service reference to your web service and make the call. Here's [a post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a1647f10-9aa4-4b0c-bbd9-dfa51a9fab8e/adding-wcf-service-refere.aspx) that explains adding reference to a WCF service from Visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to tackle this, but whichever approach you take it is probably best to run the scheduled task outside of the web process.

You could create a simple console application that does the required work, and setup a cron job to run it on Mac OS X (similar to Scheduled Tasks in Windows).  Alternatively you could use something like Quartz.Net to create jobs with a schedule and then run the process as a daemon on Mac OS.

The distinction between the two is that the daemon runs constantly and does work according to the schedule defined by the program, the console application runs only as needed and is triggered by a system level process such as cron.

Comment: But I must write exactly web service :(

Comment: A webservice can't do anything by itself without being invoked.  You need to schedule the thing that invokes it, not the webservice itself.